# One of my client has an issue with shipping calulation based on attributes in Presta shop?

Tags: prestashop

I want to know any option to calculate the shipping cost based on attributes,for example if a product will have different sizes and shipping has to calculate based on sizes

Please help me to solve this problem in presta shop

Comment: What code do you have so far? And how does your question is connected with [tag:matrix-inverse] tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can try all combinations. It may be slow. Maybe you can use  linear or dynamic programming.